# What's the meaning of Lucifel's corrected years in the opening?

Tags: religion, el-shaddai-ascension-of-metatron

The opening to [*El Shaddai: Ascension of the Metatron*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Shaddai%3a_Ascension_of_the_Metatron) begins with [Lucifel saying](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LKdmChm96A)

> Let me tell you a tale. It took place 360,000 - no, 14,000 years ago. Well. To me it seems like yesterday. To you, could be tomorrow.

Where do these measurements come from? Is it a reference to real-world debate about the timing of the events in [the Book of Enoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Enoch), or is it simply to add more non-specifics to the dream-like nature of the game?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the specific measurements are concerned; 14,000 years ago was roughly the end of the last ice age and the entry of modern man into the Americas or the so-called 'Clovis comet impact'. 360,000 years ago was the time of the last [great eruption](http://www.go4thesummit.com/KiliGeology.html) of Mount Kilimanjaro. There's no indication that either of the dates correspond with anything in the *Book of Enoch*.

Quite why [Lucifel](http://elshaddai.wikia.com/wiki/Lucifel) (or Takeyasu Sawaki) decided to use those specific times is unclear. The most likely explanation is, as you've already indicated, that it's simply a throwaway line to show that Lucifel isn't that fussed about giving us a **definitive** timescale. As far as he's concerned, ***all that we need to know is that it happened***.

On top of that, the fact that he's an immortal time traveller suggests that he may simply not *remember* when it happened.

Per the official gamer's guide;

> Lucifel is one of Heaven's greatest, if not greatest, archangels **and
>   has the ability to freely travel through time.** As commanded by God, he
>   acts as support for Enoch along with the other guardian angels. He is
>   quite fond of Enoch and is therefore very cooperative.